Why is setuptools not including a (non-package) top-level module in the generated wheel?
I have a Python project that I configure with pyproject.toml and build with pyproject-build. The lines relating to the build and which files to include in the distribution packages from the pyproject.toml are:
[build-system]
requires = ['setuptools']
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ['psrc']

Under psrc/ I have five modules, three of which are import packages (directories, two namespace packages and one with an explicit __init__.py) and the other two of which are plain modules in files (conftest.py and python_pt.py). The former, presumably through some magic, is correctly excluded from the wheel built by pyproject-build as a pytest configuration file. But the latter, pytest_pt.py, is a module that I wish to include in the distribution packages.
That module does appear in the source distribution package (sdist) r8format-0.0.2.tar.gz, under the psrc/ directory, but is not present in the wheel under that directory, r8format-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl that's built. Why is this file/module being excluded? When imported, pytest_pt is a top level module just like bastok, binary or cmtconv, except that it's not a package module, just a regular module.
I should also note that if I do an editable install (i.e., pip install -e from a directory or a git+https: URL), the pytest_pt module is available and works fine.
I have tried adding include psrc/pytest_pt.py to a MANIFEST.in file, but that seems to make no difference.
I suppose I could just hack this by creating a pytest_pt directory and moving pytest_pt.py to pytest_pt/__init__.py, but having to do that seems a bit silly.
Possibly related (but let me know if I should ask this as a separate question), I also have recursive-include doc/ * in my MANIFEST.in. This exhibits the same behaviour; those files appear in the sdist regardless of whether that line is present, but never appear in the wheel either way.

For convenience, below I refer to .py files as "modules" and directories
containing .py files as "(import) packages" even though these are not
actually modules and packages, but just the files from which one
creates them.
Setuptools Configuration and Behaviour
A summary and some details of how setuptools decides which files to put
into the wheel file is given in the setuptools documentation at Package
Discovery and Namespace Packages. This is not complete, however;
there are a number of package-related configuration directives not listed
there that are instead listed at Configuring setuptools using
pyproject.toml files. The setuptools-specific configuration
directives there go under the [tool.setuptools] table in
pyproject.toml. (All configuration directives mentioned below are under
[tool.setuptools] unless specifically mentioned otherwise.)
There are three ways in which the files and directories for the packages
be chosen:
Automatic discovery using src-layout:
This is used when there is a src/ directory at the top level and
setuptools configuration directives are not specified. Though the
documentation claims that only the packages and py_modules directives
will disable automatic discovery, other options seem to disable it too. In
particular, merely adding [tool.setuptools.packages.find] to your config
(even with nothing under it, making it an empty table), appears to disable
automatic discovery. (This is why the configuration in the question is not
using src-layout, or any, automatic discovery.)
Renaming the psrc/ directory to src/ and changing where = 'psrc' to
where = 'src' produces the same problem as in the question: top-level
modules that are not directories are excluded. Removing entirely the where = directive allows automatic discovery with src-layout to activate, and
pytest_pt.py and conftest.py then appear in the wheel.
So this is one potential solution, though I would need to add some sort of
exclude directive to avoid including conftest.py.
Automatic discovery using flat-layout:
Also called "adhoc," this too is activated only when certain setuptools
configuration directives are not supplied (see above), but when there is no
src/ directory. It assumes that there is a single module (either a .py
file or an import package directory) at the top level and attempts to
find it.
It uses a long list of excludes to try to avoid including anything
that's not a module, and if it does find more than one module at the top
level, it refuses to create a distribution archive.
This seems mainly handy for very small, simple projects that include as few
files as possible at the top level. The more other things (documentation,
test scripts, ...) you have at the top level, the more likely this is to
fail. I recommend you simply don't use this.
Custom discovery:
tools.setuptools.packages.find is a table that controls custom discovery
behaviour. Setting anything in this, or even setting it to an empty table,
disables automatic discovery. This is what is being used in the question
above.
While not documented, it appears that by default custom discovery will
never include top-level files, but only top-level directories. Not even
the find.include directive overrides this: adding include = ['p*', 'c*'] to that configuration will exclude bastok, include cmtconv, but
still exclude pytest_pt.py and conftest.py
A Solution
The documentation doesn't seem to state what py-modules in the
[pyproject.toml] table does. (The entry for it says, "See tip below'; the
tip merely describes what happens when it's left unspecified.)
However, experimentation shows that it can be used to add additional modules
to the build. So adding the following to the original pyproject.toml
includes pytest_pt.py in the wheel, fixing the problem.
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ['pytest_pt']

